# Generating sound according to a mathematical function

Tags: functions, sound

I would like to get sound clips that essentially are frequencies varying according to certain recognizable math functions like **sin, tan, floor, absolute value** etc.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmitSound.html ... `Play[Sin[1000 t^2], {t, 0, 1}]`

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: you may find this interesting as well ... http://tones.wolfram.com/generate/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at,

[Music Package](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Music/guide/MusicPackage.html)
[MUSIC PACKAGE TUTORIAL](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Music/tutorial/Music.html)
[Sound and Sonification](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SoundAndSonification.html)
[Signal Processing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SignalProcessing.html)
[Sound](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sound.html)
[The Representation of Sound](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheRepresentationOfSound.html)

```
<< Music`  
Play[Sin[2 \[Pi] Aflat4 t] + Sin[2 \[Pi] Eflat5 t], {t, 0, 0.2}]
```

[image]

And a verry nice external Site [The Physics Hypertextbook](http://physics.info/music/)

N.B.: The distinction between music and noise is mathematical form. Music is ordered sound. Noise is disordered sound.